# Friend operator declaration in a template class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a nice problem with a friend operator declared in a template class and an explicit instantiation of the class like this:

```
template<class T>
class IneqCmp{
    friend bool operator!=(T a, T b){
        return !(a==b);
    }
};

struct IntCont{
    int x;
    bool operator==(IntCont that) const{
        return x==that.x;
    }
};
template class IneqCmp<IntCont>;
int main(){
    IntCont a{1}, b{2};
    while(a!=b);
}
```

I think operator!=(IntCont, IntCont) should be instantiated at the point of instantiation of IneqCmp<IntCont> but it isn't. Why?

Comment: @chris: That `friend` is correct. It means that the `operator!=` defined inside the class in that line is actually a free function in the enclosing namespace (rather than defining a member function). It is actually a very interesting trick.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, Oh, I've never seen it used in such context, just declaring a normal other friend function definition.

Comment: The interesting part of the trick is that it will generate a non-template function for each instantiation of the template. The next *interesting* feature (for most people, not for Hristo) is that it will only be found through ADL, which means that it is a *generic* implementation in the shape of a free function but not polluting the namespace...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with the code above is not whether `operator!=` is or not defined, but the fact that it will never be found by lookup<sup>*</sup>.

When you declare a function as a friend of a class the declaration is *strange* in the sense that it declares a namespace level function, but the declaration of it will only be available through ADL on the enclosing type. Because your `operator!=` does not take `IneqComp` as any of the two arguments, it is effectively impossible to find through lookup.

If what you want to do is providing a default implementation of the `operator!=` that will be available to a set of types, you can tackle the problem in different ways.

First, you can add `IneqCmp` to the ADL set by using inheritance:

```
struct IntCont : IneqCmp<IntCont> {
   // ...
};
```

Because ADL looks in the class of the argument, and also in the base classes, this will effectively trigger lookup inside `IneqCmp<IntCont>` and that will find the `friend` declaration and thus the free function.

Another alternative would be to add a namespace where the generic `operator!=` will be defined (so that it won't be found otherwise) and a `tag` type. Then inherit from that tag:

```
namespace inequality_comparable {
   struct tag {};
   template <typename T>
   bool operator!=( T const & a, T const & b ) {
      return !(a==b);
   }
}
struct IntCont : inequality_comparable::tag {
};
bool operator==( IntCont const & a, IntCont const & b ) {
   return ...;
}
int main() {
    IntCont a,b;
    std::cout << a != b << "\n";
}
```

The trick here is that because `inequality_comparable::tag` is a base of your type, it will add the namespace `inequality_comparable` to lookup. When the compiler encounters `a != b` in `main` it will try to use an `operator!=` defined in the current scope, the class `IntCont` and it's bases and the namespace where `IntCont` and its bases are defined.

---

<sup>*</sup> If you want to verify that the operator has actually be generated, try to add it:

```
bool operator!=(IntCont a, IntCont b){
    return !(a==b);
}
```

If the operator has been defined because of the instantiation of `IneqCmp` then that will trigger a compiler error. Alternatively, you can just compile and inspect the generated object file for the symbol.

Comment: I'm wondering will statement `template class IneqCmp<IntCont>;` instantiate the class template along with all of it's member functions too? or member function instantiation will be left since it's not used?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Explicit instantiation of a class template will instantiate all members.